# Convert json to Markdown Table in bash

Tags: json, bash, markdown, jq

I am trying to convert the below json to a markdown table(GitHub docs(.md file)), however not able to do so.

```
{
   "service_1":"abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com",
   "service_2":"def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com",
   "service_3":"xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com"

}
```

Command I tried:

```
cat json_file | jq -r '{"NAME": "ENDPOINT_ID"} + . | to_entries[] | "\(.key)\t\(.value)"'
```

Output I am getting:

```
 NAME         ENDPOINT-ID
service_1    abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com
service_2    def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com
service_3    xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com
```

The above output when committed to README.md github file losses its indentation(spaces) and is not properly divided into rows and columns, leading to bad visualization.

Link that I went through:

```
https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables
```

Expected output:

```
|    NAME    | ENDPOINT_ID |
| --------   | -------- |
| service_1  | abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com   |
| service_2  | def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com   |
| service_3  | xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semi hard-coded solution could look like:

```
"|NAME|ENDPOINT_ID|\n|------|------|\n" + 
    (to_entries | map("|\(.key)|\(.value)|") | join("\n"))
```

1. Hard-coded header + second line
2. Loop ([`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D)) over [`to_entires`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to use `key` and `value`

   1. Create a string were we surround key and value in `|`
   2. [`join()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) those lines with a newline (`\n`)

The above will output:

---

```
|NAME|ENDPOINT_ID|
|------|------|
|service_1|abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
|service_2|def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
|service_3|xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
```

---

Which renders as

| NAME | ENDPOINT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| service_1 | abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |
| service_2 | def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |
| service_3 | xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |

---

#### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qxJZ6OBQQ05)

Answer (score 2):

Very slightly less hard coded than @0stone0's answer:

```
% jq -r  '{"NAME": "ENDPOINT_ID"} + {"---": "---"} + . | to_entries[] | "|\(.key)|\(.value)|"'<<-eof                                                                                                   55ms
{
   "service_1":"abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com",
   "service_2":"def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com",
   "service_3":"xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com"

}
eof
```

Gives me:

```
|NAME|ENDPOINT_ID|
|---|---|
|service_1|abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
|service_2|def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
|service_3|xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com|
```

Looks right in github preview:
[image]

Comment: Not sure how this is 'less hard coded' xD

Comment: I don't mean to say it's a relevant difference or better, but you combined the formatting with the data in your header and separator rows, while I only have newlines and pipe characters in the formatting step.

Comment: Ow no, didn't read it like that, just out of curiosity, I started with a solution like yours, but since that leaves a trailing newline, I went for the map/join way. Thanks for clarifying btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

convert **jq** output to *csv* and then display result with [csview](https://github.com/wfxr/csview) utility

```
$ cat json_file |jq -r '{"NAME": "ENDPOINT_ID"} + . |to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @csv' |csview -s Markdown

| NAME      | ENDPOINT_ID                     |
|-----------|---------------------------------|
| service_1 | abc-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |
| service_2 | def-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |
| service_3 | xyz-endpoint.vpce.amazonaws.com |
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

there is this tool that can do the conversion, and also supports some extra options:
https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jtbl

example:

```
cat json_file | jtbl
```